# How to display Attribute Group Name on Product page in Magento 1.9.0.1?

Tags: attributes, rwd, attribute-set

I would like to create an Attribute Sets with more grouped Attribute inside. In admin, the custom attributes are displayed in groups (tabs) as I created them. But, on the product page, all the attributes are listed together, without displaying the Attribute Group Name before listing the Attributes in that Group.

How can I display also the Attribute Group names, not only the attributes in Magento 1.9.0.1 RWD theme?

- I tried extension "Display Attribute grouped by Attribute-Sets"  it worked on default theme but in RWD theme Additional Information Tab becomes hidden.

References: 

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438750/how-to-display-attribute-group-name-on-product-page 

 2. http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/display-attribute-grouped-by-attribute-sets.html

Any help would be appreciated great.
Thank you.

Comment: Hi people, is there any way for the above issue. I've been searching for long time.

Comment: Using [this](http://www.webguys.de/magento/attributes-als-attribute-set-im-webshop-darstellen), it should work. I had successfully implemented this. What's the error message are you getting in "RWD" theme?

Comment: Please check the link that May help you  -  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21584274/get-attributes-by-attribute-group-magento